# android sqlite help to fire my own query?

Tags: android, sqlite, intersect

hello guys i have a simple intersect query works fine for sqlite3 console on windows
But how can i fire it and retrieve results in android sqlite database.

eg.

```sql
 SELECT b_name FROM bus,route,station WHERE s_name='STAITON_NAME'
 AND route.b_id=bus.b_id AND route.s_id=station.s_id INTERSECT
 SELECT b_name FROM bus,route,station WHERE s_name='STATION_NAME' AND route.b_id=bus.b_id AND route.s_id=station.s_id;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried?

Comment: i dont know how to fire two queries at once.

Comment: The query you listed is a single query, isn't it?

Comment: I only see 1 query, as per your question...

Comment: yes it is one query but has intersect in between this means i need to pass two different STATION_NAMES... so how could it be...

Comment: [SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery\(\)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Answer (score 0):

To fire a query, use [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29).
To pass two different station names, use two different parameters:

```java
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT ... WHERE s_name = ? AND ..."+
                       "... WHERE s_name = ? AND ...",
                new String[] { station1, station2 });
```